# Javascript one function name in multiple files

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I need is pretty simple, although I don't know if possible..

I'm attaching all my event handlers to the object themselves instead of to `$(document)`.

But, I need to attach them on the `.ready()` method, to make sure the object is created before the handler is attached. Since there are a lot of handlers to attach, to keep my code cleaner I want to create a function called `attachHandlers()` that will be called on `document.ready()`.

But.. this function should execute codes that are in multiple files.

My question is.. is there a way of declaring the same function multiple times, and then calling it just once to execute them all?

Comment: _"My question is.. is there a way of declaring the same function multiple times, and then calling it just once to execute them all?"_ Not following this portion of requirement ? Do you want to call multiple functions at `.ready()`

Comment: Javascript files are loaded as the contents of script elements. When the "load" event of the window fires, all elements on the page (including <script> ones) hav already been loaded. I don't understand what's not straight forward about this. Does jQuery monkey about and make life harder than plain vanilla JS does? I'd simply attach a function to the window's load event and then do as I please with gay abandon - can't you simply do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But.. this function should execute codes that are in multiple files.
>
> My question is.. is there a way of declaring the same function
>   multiple times, and then calling it just once to execute them all?

If interpret Question correctly, you want to request `javascript` from multiple files at `.ready()` . You can create an array containing `url` of file to request, use [`$.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when), [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map), [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getScript) to call the `javascript` within the files

> `jQuery.getScript( url [, success ] )`  Returns: `jqXHR` 
>   Description:
>   Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then
>   execute it.
>
> The script is executed in the global context, so it can refer to other
>   variables and use jQuery functions. Included scripts can have some
>   impact on the current page.

$(document).ready(function() {

```
  var files = ["1.js", "2.js", "3.js"];

  $.when.apply($, $.map(files, function(file) {
    // request file
    return $.getScript(file)
  }))
  .then(function() {
    // complete
    // do stuff
  }, function err(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // handle error
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a global JS file that has this function (and future functions that you want to be run on all pages). Call this script at the top of each file in the head element. Calling it in the head should do what you need (at least that is what i use in my projects and works for me).

Answer (score 0):

Can u package your multiple files in modules and every one of them has a method attachHandlers? Then try use requirejs to load all of them. In document.ready, call the attachHandlers method from all these modules? It will be neater