# including multiple script files in html using a for loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a folder with multiple .js files(I have the file number count in a variable)

Is it possible to "include" all the js scripts using a for loop?

Something like:

```
for(i = 0; i <= file_count; i++) {
   include('scriptname' + i)
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem you are facing ? What did not work ? `PHP` is executed on the server before web-page is rendered on `browser`.... You are attempting something _reverse_ which is not possible.. With `PHP-for-loop`, this could be achieved..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A: Javascript one function name in multiple files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36244422/javascript-one-function-name-in-multiple-files/)

Answer (score 3):

declare  a php array inside a php file (call it "file_names.php") and write names of all .js files

```
<?php 

$file_array=array('file1.js','file2.js')
?>
```

then include the php file in your desired page and iterate over the array inside your page's HTML header tag

```
include('file_names.php')

<?php foreach($file in $file_array){ ?>

<script src='<?php echo $file; ?>'></script>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `include('scriptname' + i + '.js');` if filenames are of form scriptname0.js, scriptname1.js and so on! Also remember to call this PHP for loop inside a HTML `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of options available to you.
If you are using jQuery (other frameworks offer equal functionality) then there is a method called [getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) which will likely suit your needs. If you are doing this manually then you will need to create `script` elements using [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and insert them into the `head` or `body` as appropriate.

You are advised to try and use a helper function though as there are a number of considerations when loading external resources, not least of which is ensuring they have actually loaded before attempting to make use of them.

Comment: Sorry, just spotted the `php` tag on this one. The code looks, for all the world, like a bit of JS and the jQuery tag rather suggests this should be a client, rather than server side solution. Apologies for discriminating.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add the js files to head section as below

```
    for(i = 0; i <= file_count; i++) {
    var jsfile = 'scriptname' + i ;  
    $('head').append($('<script>').prop('type', 'text/javascript').prop('src', jsFile)); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the file names of script, then Yes you can like this,

```
for(i = 0; i <= file_count; i++) {
   var script = document.createElement( "script" );
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.src = "scriptname"+i+".js"; //whatever the filename
   $("head").append(script);
}
```